# Points erased from the lightcone

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, topology, causality

Regarding the topological condition of global hyperbolicity, which affirms that the future and the past of two points $p$ and $q$ must have compact closure, when does the lightcone contains points which have been erased and hence it is not compact? What are some examples of that? I figure time travel would make that closure non-compact, but I don't understand what implies (the consequences in "real life").
Can someone provide a intuitive answer?

Comment: Do you mean the intersection of the future of $p$ and the past of $q$ must have compact closure? What do you mean by "points that have been erased"?

Comment: Yes. I mean points removed from spacetime just like Hawking discusses in The nature of spacetime in page 3. These points imply that the null geodesic which leaves from them have no past points.

Comment: The simplest example is Minkowski space minus one point. It will lie on a light cone, making it non-compact.